# should i change data table column datatype after filled with data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I am trying to change data table column datatype using c#.

i have tried like below code :

```
DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Int32);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

but it throw an exception where fees column come to import.Error Comes Like you can not change datatype of fees column after filled data table.

```
int startvalue = Convert.ToInt32(lblSelectionStart.Text);
int endvalue = Convert.ToInt32(lblSelectionEnd.Text);
var dv1 = new DataView { Table = dt };
dv1.RowFilter = "fees >=" + startvalue + " and fees <=" + endvalue;
dt = dv1.ToTable();
```

i want to change fees column into int from string.

Comment: Did the data in `dt` come out of a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data in dt came out of a database, modify the database query to perform the int conversion

```
--oracle example
SELECT to_number(fees) as feesint FROM ...

--sqls example
SELECT convert(int, fees) as feesint FROM ...

--MySQL example
SELECT convert(fees, integer) as feesint FROM ...
```

If the data in dt did not come from a database, add another column to dt, of type int and parse all the data into it:

```
dt.Columns.Add("feeint", typeof(Int)32);
foreach(var ro in dt.Rows)
  ro["feeint"] = int.Parse((string)ro["fees"]);
```

Later when you want to put a row filter:

```
dv1.RowFilter = $"FeesInt >= {startValue} AND FeesInt <= {endValue}";
```

Remember to use the feesint converted column, not the fees column, which is a string

Comment: I'm using MySQL for retrieve data into dt. I also convert that fees column into int but that does not work properly and thrown an error like >= operation not work in system.string and system.int.

Comment: I adjusted my answer slightly